# Creating PDF for Java applications

Tags: java, pdf

How to create pdf with complex design views in Java?I have tried it using jasper reports.Is there Any Ideas for creating PDF for Income tax forms?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) project. I believe you can create PDFs using this library, although it is more commonly used in Lucene to convert PDFs to text to allow indexing.

Answer (score 4):

A commonly used Java API to create PDF files is [**iText**](http://itextpdf.com/). Give it a look. API documentation can be found [here](http://api.itextpdf.com/), code examples can be found [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/index.php), a tutorial can be found [here](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/iText/).

A good but less widely known Java API is [**OOo API**](http://api.openoffice.org/) wherein you can create any [OOo document](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide) to your taste and finally [export to PDF](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Tutorials/PDF_export).

Comment: How to create all form fields using iText.I want to create PDf for Form16 Dynamically.will it support for this Complex Designs?

Comment: I have no idea what *exactly* you mean with "form fields" and "Form16". Please be a bit more specific. I've at least added links to documentation, examples and a tutorial.

Comment: Form16 is the form which is provided for filing Income Tax. Below Link is sample format.I want create it Dynamically by filling All Values.
http://www.taxguru.in/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/form-itr-1-2009-10.pdf

I hope that you understand my requirement.

Comment: @Palani:  How to do it for income tax forms specifically is where your expertise comes in.  I could be wrong, but I doubt there is any specific API for creating specific income tax forms in PDF via java.  Maybe when you've succeeded you can contribute it back to the community and then we'll have one.

Comment: There are many ways to do this using iText, but the easiest is to use a different authoring tool (like Acrobat) to insert form fields in the PDF.  Then you use iText to fill in and flatten those fields.  There are plenty of examples on the iText site for doing this, and the iText In Action book is a great resource.

Comment: @Kevin Day: One of My concept is same as what you said. is it possible to give some description How to add the form fields by creating using Acrobat?

Comment: That would be a question more appropriate for an Acrobat users forum, but I'm sure the Forms tool in Acrobat would come into play.

Comment: I know this is a little old post but still I have a question. Somebody please clear my doubts. itext is a paid library as per today i am going i am able to see that there is a 30 days trial ........ things are there into the pages on url https://pages.itextpdf.com/Free-Trial.html?utm_expid=.7ElZicjOQMKuJz5kFeYnhw.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.itextpdf.com%2Fitext7%2Fdownload-and-install-information%2FJava

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) or [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) to do the conversion as long as you can install OpenOffice somewhere.  They work on many platforms and can be Java controlled and will save you the hassle of learning the OOo UNO API.

Answer (score 0):

Design your **complex** PDF Form with the appropriate tools, something like Acrobat Professional. Then from your Java code, you generate an FDF file (Form Data Format) and let the PDF Reader do the merging or you do it from the server-side and stream back the result.

Possible solutions to process FDF are [Adobe Java FDF Toolkit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html) or [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

one approach that requires very little programming is converting your Java object to XML using the Java Binding API for XML (JABX) and then use apache FOP (XSL-FO) to create the PDF from XML. The adavantage of this approach is that is almost 100% declarative, .i.e no programming involved other than executing jabx and apache fop. If you want a tool to create the XSL-FO template, look at J4L FO Designer

Answer (score 0):

You can try ITextPDF.jar Add this jar to your application and please go through the examples to know more about the tags and design procedure used for creating a PDF Document. Check this link for a simple exmaple http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=12